# SQL Server update database column

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a SQL Server database and I need to multiply the values of multiple columns:

```
Var1  |  Var2  |  Var3  | Product
----------------------------------
  5        5        3
```

What should I use to have `Var1`, `Var2` and `Var3` get multiplied and update column `Product`?

Comment: What database engine are you using? ex. SQL Server, MySQL, etc. Also, is this to update the Product for every row, or just a single row?

Comment: Im using SQL Server and it is to update for every row

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myUnknownTableFromMyInCompleteQuestion 
SET Product = (Var1 * Var2 * Var3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to build the table *without* the product column.  Then add it in as a computed column:

```
alter table t add product as (var1 * var2 * var3);
```

`product` will be calculated when it is used.  It will always be up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `update` statement to update product

```
update table
   set Product = var1 * var2 * var3
where product is null;
```